# ASP.NET Pragmatically Play Sound at Client Side

Tags: asp.net, audio

I need to play music when certain condition is met, the webpage is being postback (for refreshing GridView purpose) for every 10 seconds. It play the role as similar to notification sound, like:

```
  If x > 2,
     playsound()
  End If
```

I have tried the below coding. Unfortunately, it fails to play sound at client side.

```
  Dim player As New System.Media.SoundPlayer
  player.SoundLocation = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\music.wav"
  player.Load()
  player.Play()
```

If there is any method to play the sound at ASP NET webpage only when it satisfy certain conditions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the `BGSOUND`

```
<BGSOUND SRC="music.wav" LOOP="2">
```

You can also refer this MSDN forum: [Playing Sound in Client-Side](http://forums.asp.net/t/1630105.aspx?Playing%20Sound%20in%20Client%20Side%20)